# How do I read browser header sequence from java web server?

Tags: java, browser, request-headers, fingerprinting

I have started being interested in browser fingerprints.
As far as I understand: "The header order of each browser is fixed and cannot be changed in the browser settings."
So,... to a start, I want to read the browser headers in the order in which they are sent by the browser.

I have tried with:

```
Ennumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
While (headerNames!=null && headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
   String key = headerNames.nextElement();
   <...more code...>
}
```

Unfortunately, nextElement() does not provide the same sequence as sent by the browser.

Therefore, what are the Java alternatives?

Note: my application runs on an Apache/Tomcat webserver on a webhotel, i.e. I am not able to make changes to the configuration of the Apache/Tomcat webserver.

Comment: Not possible. The fix is to read the input 'raw', but given that you're in a constrained environment, there's nothing you can do. As a general principle, "I run in a highly constrained environment" just doesn't mesh with "I want to intentionally ignore established convention and approach specifically in order to do stuff that the frameworks were not intended to do", and that's exactly what you're doing here. Move away from the hotel thing and you can do this.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, thank you for the clear answer, even though it is not the one I had hoped for.
I have considered moving away from this "hotel thing" as you call it, for some time, because they are several generations  behind updating the SW (e.g still Java 1.7).
Assuming that I am in control of everything, what is the way forward?

Comment: "The fix is to read the input 'raw', ". How do I do that, I mean from where can I read the input?